# I am getting error 'TypeError: i.grid is null' in on page change in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am getting the error "Type Error: i.grid is null" on page or page size change in JQ Grid pager with server side pagination:

[image]

How can I fix it? This is my code:

```
<script>
    $("#list1").jqGrid({
      url: "GetNotesReportDetails",
      postData: { BillStatus: status, pageNumber: pageNumber, PageSize: PageSize },
      datatype: "json",
      mtype: "POST",
      colNames: ["ID", "First Name", "Last Name", ],
      colModel: [
              { name: "ID", index: "ID", hidden: true, key: true },            
              { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 50, align: "left", sortable: true },
              { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 50, align: "left", sortable: true }, 
      ],  
      multiselect: true,
      rowNum: 20,
      rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
      width: 1200,
      height: "100%",
      pager: $("#pager1"),
      viewrecords: true,
      cellEdit: true, 
      sortorder: "asc",
      sortable: true,
      loadonce: true,
      hidegrid: false,
      ignoreCase: true,
      caption: "Reports List",
      loadComplete: function (data) {
        var page = $('#list1').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page');
        var lastpage = $("#list1").getGridParam('lastpage');
        if ($("#hdnPageNumber").val() == "") {
          $(".ui-pg-input").val(1);
        }
        else {
          $(".ui-pg-input").val($("#hdnPageNumber").val());
        }

        $("#hdnTotalRows").val(data.total);
        var currentPage = parseInt($(".ui-pg-input").val());
        var lastPage = parseInt($("#hdnTotalRows").val());
        var PageSize = parseInt($(".ui-pg-selbox", this.p.pager).val());
        var TotalPages = data.total <= PageSize ? 1 : Math.ceil(data.total / PageSize);
        $("#sp_1_pager1").text(data.total <= PageSize ? 1 : Math.ceil(data.total/PageSize));
        var currentRecordCount = parseInt($("#list1").getGridParam("reccount"));
        var a = PageSize * (currentPage - 1) + 1;
        var b = currentRecordCount * currentPage;

        var c = lastPage;
        $(".ui-paging-info").html("View " + a + "-" + b + " 0f " + c);

        if (currentPage < TotalPages) {
            $('#next_pager1').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
            $('#last_pager1').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
            $('#prev_pager1').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
            $('#first_pager1').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#next_pager1').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            $('#last_pager1').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        }
        if (currentPage == 1) {
            $('#prev_pager1').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            $('#first_pager1').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        }
      },
      onPaging: function (pgButton) {
        var pagerId = this.p.pager.substr(1); 
        var currentPage = parseInt($(".ui-pg-input").val()); 
        var lastPage = parseInt($("#hdnTotalRows").val());

        if (currentPage - 1 == lastPage - 1)
          $("#list1").setGridParam({ page: lastPage }).trigger("reloadGrid"); 
        var currentRecordCount = $("#list1").getGridParam("reccount"); 
        var recordsPerPage = $("#list1").getGridParam("rowNum"); 
        var PageSize = $(".ui-pg-selbox", this.p.pager).val();

        var newValue = 0; 

        if (pgButton.indexOf("next") >= 0)
          currentPage = ++currentPage;
        else if (pgButton.indexOf("prev") >= 0)
          currentPage = --currentPage;
        else if (pgButton.indexOf("last") >= 0)
          currentPage = $("#gridId").getGridParam('lastpage');
        else if (pgButton.indexOf("first") >= 0)
          currentPage = 1;
        currentRecordCount = $("#list1").getGridParam("reccount");

        $("#hdnPageNumber").val(currentPage);
        $("#hdnPageSize").val(PageSize);
        bindReports("1", currentPage, PageSize);
        $(".ui-pg-selbox").val(PageSize);
      }
    }).navGrid("#pager1", { refresh: false, excel: true, add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, 
                                                                                  {},
                                                                                  {}, 
                                                                                  { sopt: ["cn"] } 
        );
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });

</script>
```

Comment: What is the jqGrid version you're using.

Comment: Please use a code block (indent four spaces or click the `{}` button to format your code. Also look at the preview to make sure everything looks alright before you post. Thank you.

Comment: I'm using jqGrid  4.6.0

Comment: Thank you Anders to format code